# How to sort Firebase Realtime Database HashMap data for Recyclerview by value?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm making an app that displays shortfilms in a Horizontal Recyclerview. Right now I am getting all the shortfilms populated in the Recyclerview, but I would like to order them by "rankOrder".

I'm getting the dataSnapshot as HashMap and I know that HashMaps are not ordered. I've tried `map.toList().sortedby....`, comparators, and a lot of other things, but I don't know how to sort my recyclerview by "rankOrder"

Can someone help me? I want the shortfilms in my recyclerview to be ordered by "rankOrder". "rankOrder" is an Int.

I'm using kotlin.
I'm somewhat new at this so please explain it in detail.

Here's my "HomeView.kt"

```
val originalStart =  trendingMoviesDB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
   override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
       //get Channel IDs
       for (ChannelIDs in dataSnapshot.children) {
           val channelID = ChannelIDs.key!!

           trendingMoviesDB.child(channelID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object :
               ValueEventListener {
               override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                   //get Channel Names
                   for (ChannelNames in dataSnapshot.children) {
                       val channelName = ChannelNames.key!!
                       trendingMoviesDB.child(channelID).child(channelName)
                           .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                               object : ValueEventListener {
                                   override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

  for (MovieID in dataSnapshot.children) {
   val movieID = MovieID.key!!

   trendingMoviesDB.child(channelID).child(channelName).child(movieID).orderByChild("rankOrder")
       .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
               override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

                   val map: HashMap<String, Any> =
                       dataSnapshot.value as HashMap<String, Any>

                   val mTitle = map["movieTitle"] as String
                   val mMovieFeaturePhoto = map["movieFeaturePhoto"] as String
                   val mChannelId = map["channelID"] as String
                   val mChannelName = map["channelName"] as String
                   val mMovieID = map["movieID"] as String
                   val mMovieDescription = map["movieDescription"] as String
                   val mMovieUrl = map["movieURL"] as String
                   val mMovieCredits = map["movieCredits"] as String
                   val mTimeStamp = map["timeStamp"] as Int
                   val mRankOrder = map["rankOrder"] as Int

                   fvOriginals.addAll(
                       listOf(
                           TrendingMoviesModel(
                               movieTitle = mTitle,
                               movieFeaturePhoto = mMovieFeaturePhoto,
                               movieDescription = mMovieDescription,
                               movieCredits = mMovieCredits,
                               channelName = mChannelName,
                               channelID = mChannelId,
                               movieURL = mMovieUrl,
                               movieID = mMovieID,
                               rankOrder = mRankOrder,
                               timeStamp = mTimeStamp

                           )
                       )
                   )

                   originalsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

               }

               override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
               }
           })
}
```

Here is my RecyclerAdapter:

```
class TrendingMovieAdapter(val context: Context, private val fvOriginals: List<TrendingMoviesModel>): RecyclerView.Adapter<TrendingMovieAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(TrendingMovieCellBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false))

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(fvOriginals[position])

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val model = fvOriginals[position]
            var gMovieTitle : String = model.movieTitle
            var gMovieFeaturePhoto : String = model.movieFeaturePhoto
            var gMovieDesc : String = model.movieDescription
            var gChannelID : String = model.channelID
            var gChannelName : String = model.channelName
            var gMovieID : String = model.movieID
            var gMovieCredits : String = model.movieCredits
            var gMovieUrl : String = model.movieURL


            val intent = Intent(context,MovieDetailActivity::class.java)

            intent.putExtra("iMovieTitle", gMovieTitle)
            intent.putExtra("iMovieFeaturePhoto", gMovieFeaturePhoto)
            intent.putExtra("iMovieDesc", gMovieDesc)
            intent.putExtra("iChannelID", gChannelID)
            intent.putExtra("iChannelName",gChannelName)
            intent.putExtra("iMovieID", gMovieID)
            intent.putExtra("iMovieCredits",gMovieCredits)
            intent.putExtra("iMovieUrl", gMovieUrl)
            context.startActivity(intent)

        }

    }

    override fun getItemCount() = fvOriginals.size
    
    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: TrendingMovieCellBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(trendingMoviesModel: TrendingMoviesModel) {
                binding.movieTitle.text = trendingMoviesModel.movieTitle
            Glide.with(context).load(trendingMoviesModel.movieFeaturePhoto).into(binding.trendingMoviePoster)


        }
    }

}
```

Here's my model class:

```
 data class TrendingMoviesModel(
     var channelID: String = "",
     var channelName: String = "",
     var movieID: String = "",
     var movieFeaturePhoto: String = "",
     var movieTitle: String = "",
     var movieDescription: String,
     var movieURL: String = "",
     var movieCredits: String = "",
     var rankOrder: Int = 0,
     var timeStamp: Int = 0
 )
```

Here's how my data is structured in Firebase Realtime Database:

[image: Realtime Database Structure]

Comment: How do the `channelID`,  `channelName` and `movieID` iin `trendingMoviesDB.child(channelID).child(channelName).child(movieID)` relate to the JSON that you've shown?

Comment: Yes. They hold values of the paths. For example: channelID has "c1001" stored because I'm iterating over each shortfilm (child) to get the values. I'll edit the code above to show how I'm getting the keys. When someone clicks on one of the shortfilms in the recyclerview, the information is passed to another activity.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see what the listener is exactly attached to. I really recommend constructing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which would mean: 1) replace all variables with hard-coded values. 2) remove any UI elements, and instead use hard-coded values for inputs, and only logging for output, 3) Use the minimum code needed to reconstruct the problem. For example: I doubt whether you need to look up 10 fields for that.